.NET Core app refers to UNC path as local path
I'm running a .NET Core app on a Linux container and I'm trying to access a network share on a Windows server:
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server.domain.fqdn\path\directory");

FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}

I get this error:

Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/app/\server.domain.fqdn\path\directory'

This means that the app refers to the UNC path as a local path on the workdir.
How can I make it recognize that it's an UNC path and act accordingly?
